# In Matlab's Parallel Computing Toolbox, how can I choose which lines of code I send to each worker/core?

Tags: matlab, math, parallel-processing

I am running a for loop where I compute 3 variables separately and then add them all up in the end, i.e.

```
for time=0:endtime
   calculate_a(a,u);
   calculate_b(b,u);
   calculate_c(c,u);
   u=a+b+c;
 end
```

I would like to parallelise this loop so that each calculation of *a*, *b* and *c* is done by an individual worker and they are all put together for *u* calculation, i.e.:

```
   for time=0:endtime
     calculate_a(a,u); % performed by worker 1
     calculate_b(b,u); % performed by worker 2
     calculate_c(c,u); % performed by worker 3
     % all workers share their outcome and perform
     u=a+b+c;
   end
```

I am new to parallel computing in [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html). Can you help me figure out how to go about this? Also, are there any problems in creating a stand-alone program (*.exe*) from Matlab when using parallel computing?

Many thanks!

Comment: That is not how parallel computing works, you are describing multithreading. Parallel computing is the idea of having 1 thing you need to do  a lot of times and using multiple computers to give a piece of that 1 thing to each. If the things to do are different, then parallel computing is not what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `createJob`, `createTask`, `submit`, and `fetchOutputs`. The documentation is pretty clear but let me know if you need more help.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Do you know whether I would need any extra care when creating a standalone application using these tools?

Comment: That's something I don't know the answer to.